# Topological editing of vertices that are common in two adjacent polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, topology, vertices

How do you edit vertices that are common in two adjacent polygons in QGIS?

I tried to select both polygons but when editing the vertex moves only in one polygon and not in both.

Answer (score 9):

Once in edit mode, select the `vertex tool`, then on the `snapping` toolbar, select `enable topological editing` and at last left-click once on the shared vertex, move them, click a 2nd time to set the new location.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since QGIS 3.20, there is a new possibility that allows exactly what you want: [Select vertices by polygon](https://qgis.org/de/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-select-vertices-by-polygon).

With vertex-tool enabled, press the `ALT` button and left-click once with the mouse on the canvas. Than release the `ALT` button and draw a polygon around the point(s) you want to move. Finish your polygon with right-click. Then you can move the selected vertices: even without topological editing activated, vertices for both polygons will be moved.

*Screenshot: Color is set to transparent to show that there are no overlaps. 1) Press `ALT`, than make a selection of the vertices you want to move, 2) Vertices are selected, 3) Move selected vertices, 4) Now polygons with moved vertices:*
[image]